# Why doesn't GreenDao support view in database?

Tags: greendao

It's very important every ORM can support view, like Entity framework. I've a big problem, when I want to make a query and get data from two or more tables. I want to get the data in a special class.

---Edit---

For example:

Table1: tblProfile

```
 profileId | name | family
---------------------------
     1     | ali  | niazi
---------------------------
     2     | reza | jafari
```

Table2: tblJob

```
  jobId | profileId | jobTitle
 ------------------------------
    1   |     1     |  driver
 ------------------------------
    2   |     2     | analysis
 ------------------------------
    3   |     2     |programmer
```

View1: viwJobs

```
profileId | name | family  | jobTitle
-------------------------------------
     1     | ali  | niazi  | driver
-------------------------------------
     2     | reza | jafari | analysis
-------------------------------------
     2     | reza | jafari |programmer
```

But, This is just a sample, not real. I mean sometimes I wanna make a view from several tables in sqlite and I like use it in my app. How can I create a entity(class) by DaoGenerator for use that view?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, what's the specific issue?

If your issue is that greenDAO wants to create a table, you can tell greenDAO not to. Call setSkipTableCreation(false) on the entity that represents your view.

Also, you would have to create the database view yourself in a SQLiteOpenHelper.